# sauce on android error "Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnsupportedOperationError: underlying webdriver instance does not support javascript"

Tags: javascript, android, selenium, saucelabs

my test is passing on IOS and windows, but fails on Android with the following error;

Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnsupportedOperationError:
       underlying webdriver instance does not support javascript

... look familiar to anyone?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Google is your friend: https://github.com/ios-driver/ios-driver/issues/83

Comment: Thanks ^^, but I am selenium-webdriver (~> 2.49). testing android on sauce, .javascript_enabled defeats the purpose

Comment: @BurtSaxby if thats the case you're probably using an incorrect method....one that requires javascript

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem using Safari in Browserstack....by entering:

```
"javascriptEnabled": true
```

in my browser_caps....it works